# Is there a way to solve this in O(n) time complexity?

Tags: python, time-complexity

I have a list of tuples as an input like the following.

```
input = [(5,6), (6,4), (6,3), (0,5), (1,2), (2,0)]
```

Now I need to find out that in all the tuples which element was present in the first place but not in the second place of the tuple. Like in this case we have "1". The output will always be a single value.

To find this I came up with the following solution.

```
input = [(5,6),(6,4),(6,3),(0,5),(1,2),(2,0)] #input
A = []                                        #to store elements in first position of the tuple
B = []                                        #to store elements in second position of the tuple
for i in input:
    A.append(i[0])
    B.append(i[1])

for i in A:
    if i not in B:
        print (i)
```

Here, the first for loop runs n times, where n is the number of tuples in the input. So, time complexity would be O(n).
The second loop also runs n times and the if statement which checks if the element is in List B or not also take O(n) time. So time complexity of the second for loop would be O(n^2).
Hence, the time complexity of my solution would be O(n^2).

Is there a way to do this in linear time complexity?

Thank you!

Comment: Using a `set` with O(1) lookup will help rather than a list

Comment: Please link to where this is from.

Comment: @SaatvikRamani - yeah, thanks!

Comment: You can zip common elements using  ```inputa, inputb = list(zip(*input1))```

Comment: @KellyBundy there's no link to this question. Someone asked me and I couldn't come up with a linear solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
input = [(5,6),(6,4),(6,3),(0,5),(1,2),(2,0)]
A = set()
B = set()
for ele in input:
    A.add(ele[0])
    B.add(ele[1])

for ele in A:
    if not B.contains(ele):
        return ele
```

A set has O(1) lookup time hence comparing elements will take O(n) rather than O(n^2)

Answer (score 1):

For `(x,y)` in tuple we add `y` in a set and now iterate over tuple to see if `x` is in set `s` if it is present in set `s` then it's present at second place.

Time : `O(n)` ie. not nested loops.

Space : `O(n)` ie. maximum space of size of original array.

```
s = set()
input =  [(5,6), (6,4), (6,3), (0,5), (1,2), (2,0)]
for (x,y) in input :
    s.add(y)
 
for (x,y) in input :
    if x not in s:
        print x
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use two sets (`in`, `add`, and `remove` are O(1)) and only require one pass:

```
input_list = [(5, 6), (6, 4), (6, 3), (0, 5), (1, 2), (2, 0)]
candidate_first = set()
seen_second = set()
for first, second in input_list:
    seen_second.add(second)
    if first not in seen_second:
        candidate_first.add(first)
    if second in candidate_first:
        candidate_first.remove(second)
print(candidate_first)
```

**Output:**

```
{1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using set subtraction:

```py
pairs = [(5,6), (6,4), (6,3), (0,5), (1,2), (2,0)]

first, second = zip(*pairs)
result, = set(first) - set(second)

print(result) # 1
```

This will raise an error if the set difference does not have exactly one element.